# Why does my producer - consumer pattern have unexpected output?

Tags: c, multithreading, operating-system, simulation, nios

In [this excercise](http://www.ict.kth.se/courses/IS1500/2012/labos/) (producer - consumer), 3 producers are one thread each and produce prime numbers. But when I run the program, the first prime number that is consumed is not the first that it produces, so I don't get the expected output. Can you please help me find and correct the bug?

Here's the main file with the pattern:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "oslab_lowlevel_h.h"

int NextPrime( int );

#define FIFO_SIZE 10

/* Declare a structure to hold a producer's starting value,
 * and an integer for the Producer-number (Producer 1, 2 or 3). */
struct Prod {
    int startvalue;
    int id;
};

unsigned int stack1[0x400]; /* Stack for thread 1 */
unsigned int stack2[0x400]; /* Stack for thread 2 */
unsigned int stack3[0x400]; /* Stack for thread 3 */
unsigned int stack4[0x400]; /* Stack for thread 4 */
unsigned int stack5[0x400]; /* Stack for thread 5 */

/* Declare variables for the First-In-First-Out Queue */
int  Fifo[FIFO_SIZE];        /* Array holding FIFO queue data. */
int  rdaddr;                /* Next unread entry when reading from queue. */
int  wraddr;                /* Next free entry when writing into queue. */

/* Declaration of semaphore variables.
 * 
 * Sorry for the lack of comments, but part of the purpose of the lab
 * is that you should find things out by reading the actual code. */
int  rdmutex = 1;
int  wrmutex = 1;
int  nrempty = FIFO_SIZE;
int  nrfull = 0;

/*
 * fatal_error
 * 
 * Print a message, then stop execution.
 * This function never returns; after printing
 * the message, it enters an infinite loop.
 */
void fatal_error( char * msg)
{
  printf( "\nFatal error: %s\n", msg );
  while( 1 );
}

/*
 * Sleep
 * 
 * Delay execution by keeping the CPU busy for a while,
 * counting down to zero.
 */
void Sleep (int n)
{
    while (n--);
}

/*
 * Signal
 * 
 * Semaphore operation: add to semaphore,
 * possibly allowing other threads to continue.
 */
void Signal( int *sem )
{
  /* We must disable interrupts, since the operation
   * *sem = *sem + 1
   * will require several machine instructions on Nios2.
   * If we have a timer-interrupt and a thread-switch
   * somewhere in the middle of those machine instructions,
   * the semaphore will be updated twice, or not at all, or
   * in some other erroneous way.
   */
  oslab_begin_critical_region();
  *sem = *sem + 1;
  oslab_end_critical_region();
}

/*
 * Wait
 * 
 * Sempahore operation: check semaphore, and
 * wait if the semaphore value is zero or less.
 */
void Wait( int *sem )
{
  /* Disable interrupts. */
  oslab_begin_critical_region();
  while ( *sem <= 0 )
    {
      /* If we should wait, enable interrupts again. */
      oslab_end_critical_region();

      //  oslab_yield(); /* Perhaps we should yield here? */

      /* Disable interrupts again before next iteration in loop. */
      oslab_begin_critical_region();
    }
    /* We have waited long enough - the semaphore-value is now
     * greater than zero. Decrease it. */
    *sem = *sem - 1;
    /* Enable interrupts again. */
    oslab_end_critical_region();
}

/*
 * PutFifo
 * 
 * Insert an integer into the FIFO queue.
 */
void PutFifo( int tal )
{
  //  Wait (&nrempty);      /* Wait for nrempty? */
  //  Wait (&wrmutex);      /* Wait for wrmutex? */

  Fifo[wraddr] = tal;       /* Write to FIFO array. */
    //  printf("\nPutFifo:  %d ", tal); /* Optional debug output */
    //  printf("\nwraddr = %d ", wraddr); /* Optional debug output. */
  wraddr = wraddr + 1;      /* Increase index into FIFO array,
                               to point to the next free position. */
  /* Wrap around the index, if it has reached the end of the array. */
  if (wraddr == FIFO_SIZE ) wraddr = 0;

  //  Signal (&wrmutex);    /* Signal wrmutex? */
  //  Signal (&nrfull);     /* Signal nrfull? */
}

/*
 * GetFifo
 * 
 * Extract the next integer from the FIFO queue.
 */
int GetFifo( void )
{
  int retval;               /* Declare temporary for return value. */

  //  Wait (&nrfull);       /* Wait for nrfull? */
  //  Wait (&rdmutex);      /* Wait for rdmutex? */

  retval = Fifo[rdaddr];    /* Get value from FIFO array. */
    //  printf("\nGetFifo:  %d ", retval); /* Optional debug output */
    //  printf("\nrdaddr = %d ", rdaddr); /* Optional debug output */
  rdaddr = rdaddr + 1;      /* Increase index into FIFO array,
                               to point to the next free position. */
  /* Wrap around the index, if it has reached the end of the array. */
  if (rdaddr == FIFO_SIZE ) rdaddr = 0;

  //  Signal (&rdmutex);    /* Signal rdmutex? */
  //  Signal (&nrempty);    /* Signal nrempty? */

  return (retval);          /* Return value fetched from FIFO. */
}

/*
 * NextPrime
 * 
 * Return the first prime number larger than the integer
 * given as a parameter. The integer must be positive.
 * 
 * *** NextPrime is outside the focus of this assignment. ***
 * The definition of NextPrime can be found at the end of this file.
 * The short declaration here is required by the compiler.
 */
int NextPrime( int );

void Producer( struct Prod * prodstruct )
{
  int next;                 /* Will hold the prime we just produced. */
  int prodid;               /* Tells whether we are producer 1, 2 or 3. */
  next = prodstruct -> startvalue; /* Get starting value from parameter. */
  prodid = prodstruct -> id;/* Get producer number from parameter. */
  while( 1 )                /* Loop forever. */
  {
    next = NextPrime (next);/* Produce a new prime. */
    printf("\nNext Prime from producer %d is %d",prodid,next); /* Informational output. */
    PutFifo(next);          /* Write prime into FIFO. */
  //  oslab_yield();        /* Perhaps we should yield here? */ 
  }
}

void Consumer( int * tal )
{
  int next;                 /* Will hold the prime we are to consume. */
  int consid = *tal;        /* Tells whether we are consumer 1 or 2. */
  while( 1 )                /* Loop forever. */
  {
    next = GetFifo();       /* Get a newly produced prime from the FIFO. */
    printf("\nConsumer %d gets Prime %d ",consid, next); /* Informational output. */
    Sleep(2000);            /* Symbolic work. */
  //  oslab_yield();        /* Perhaps we should yield here? */ 
  }
}

int main( void )
{
  int new_thread_id; /* Thread ID variable. */
  struct Prod prod1, prod2, prod3;  /* Producer starting-values. */
  int cons1, cons2;                 /* Consumer starting-values. */

  rdaddr = 0;               /* FIFO initialization. */
  wraddr = 0;               /* FIFO initialization. */
  printf("\nSystem starting...");

  prod1.startvalue = 2000;
  prod1.id = 1;

  prod2.startvalue = 5000;
  prod2.id = 2;

  prod3.startvalue = 8000;
  prod3.id = 3;

  cons1 = 1;
  cons2 = 2;

  new_thread_id = oslab_create_thread((void *)Producer, &prod1, &(stack1[0x3ff]));
  if( new_thread_id < 0 ) fatal_error( "cannot start Producer 1" );
  printf("\nProducer %d is created with thread-ID %d", prod1.id, new_thread_id);

  new_thread_id = oslab_create_thread((void *)Producer, &prod2, &(stack2[0x3ff]));
  if( new_thread_id < 0 ) fatal_error( "cannot start Producer 2" );
  printf("\nProducer %d is created with thread-ID %d", prod2.id, new_thread_id);

  new_thread_id = oslab_create_thread((void *)Producer, &prod3, &(stack3[0x3ff]));
  if( new_thread_id < 0 ) fatal_error( "cannot start Producer 3" );
  printf("\nProducer %d is created with thread-ID %d", prod3.id, new_thread_id);

  new_thread_id = oslab_create_thread((void *)Consumer, &cons1, &(stack4[0x3ff]));
  if( new_thread_id < 0 ) fatal_error( "cannot start Consumer 1" );
  printf("\nConsumer %d is created with thread-ID %d", cons1, new_thread_id);

  new_thread_id = oslab_create_thread((void *)Consumer, &cons2, &(stack5[0x3ff]));
  if( new_thread_id < 0 ) fatal_error( "cannot start Consumer 2" );
  printf("\nConsumer %d is created with thread-ID %d", cons2, new_thread_id);

  oslab_idle(); /* Must be called here! */
}


/*
 * NextPrime
 * 
 * Return the first prime number larger than the integer
 * given as a parameter. The integer must be positive.
 */
#define PRIME_FALSE   0     /* Constant to help readability. */
#define PRIME_TRUE    1     /* Constant to help readability. */
int NextPrime( int inval )
{
   int perhapsprime;        /* Holds a tentative prime while we check it. */
   int testfactor;          /* Holds various factors for which we test perhapsprime. */
   int found;               /* Flag, false until we find a prime. */

   if (inval < 3 )          /* Initial sanity check of parameter. */
   {
     if(inval <= 0) return(1);  /* Return 1 for zero or negative input. */
     if(inval == 1) return(2);  /* Easy special case. */
     if(inval == 2) return(3);  /* Easy special case. */
   }
   else
   {
     /* Testing an even number for primeness is pointless, since
      * all even numbers are divisible by 2. Therefore, we make sure
      * that perhapsprime is larger than the parameter, and odd. */
     perhapsprime = ( inval + 1 ) | 1 ;
   }
   /* While prime not found, loop. */
   for( found = PRIME_FALSE; found != PRIME_TRUE; perhapsprime += 2 )
   {
     /* Check factors from 3 up to perhapsprime/2. */
     for( testfactor = 3; testfactor <= (perhapsprime >> 1) + 1; testfactor += 1 )
     {
       found = PRIME_TRUE;      /* Assume we will find a prime. */
       if( (perhapsprime % testfactor) == 0 ) /* If testfactor divides perhapsprime... */
       {
         found = PRIME_FALSE;   /* ...then, perhapsprime was non-prime. */
         goto check_next_prime; /* Break the inner loop, go test a new perhapsprime. */
       }
     }
     check_next_prime:;         /* This label is used to break the inner loop. */
     if( found == PRIME_TRUE )  /* If the loop ended normally, we found a prime. */
     {
       return( perhapsprime );  /* Return the prime we found. */
     } 
   }
   return( perhapsprime );      /* When the loop ends, perhapsprime is a real prime. */
}
```

The rest of the files are available [here](http://www.ict.kth.se/courses/IS1200/2013/labos/oslabcode2010ht.pdf).

When I run the code I get the expected output from the producers but I don't get the expected output for the consumers:

```
System starting...
Producer 1 is created with thread-ID 1
Producer 2 is created with thread-ID 2
Producer 3 is created with thread-ID 3
Consumer 1 is created with thread-ID 4
Consumer 2 is created with thread-ID 5
#### Thread yielded after using 1 tick.
Performing thread-switch number 1. The system has been running for 1 ticks.
Switching from thread-ID 0 to thread-ID 1.

Next Prime from producer 1 is 2003
PutFifo:  2003 
wraddr = 0 
Next Prime from producer 1 is 2011
PutFifo:  2011 
wraddr = 1 
Next Prime from producer 1 is 2017
PutFifo:  2017 
wraddr = 2 
Next Prime from producer 1 is 2027
PutFifo:  2027 
wraddr = 3 
Next Prime from producer 1 is 2029
PutFifo:  2029 
wraddr = 4 
Next Prime from producer 1 is 2039
PutFifo:  2039 
wraddr = 5 
Next Prime from producer 1 is 2053
PutFifo:  2053 
wraddr = 6 
Next Prime from producer 1 is 2063
PutFifo:  2063 
wraddr = 7 
Next Prime from producer 1 is 2069
PutFifo:  2069 
wraddr = 8 
Next Prime from producer 1 is 2081
PutFifo:  2081 
wraddr = 9 
Next Prime from producer 1 is 2083
PutFifo:  2083 
wraddr = 0 
Next Prime from producer 1 is 2087
PutFifo:  2087 
wraddr = 1 
Next Prime from producer 1 is 2089
PutFifo:  2089 
wraddr = 2 
Next Prime from producer 1 is 2099
PutFifo:  2099 
wraddr = 3 
Next Prime from producer 1 is 2111
PutFifo:  2111 
wraddr = 4 
Next Prime from producer 1 is 2113
PutFifo:  2113 
wraddr = 5 
Next Prime from producer 1 is 2129
PutFifo:  2129 
wraddr = 6 
Next Prime from producer 1 is 2131
PutFifo:  2131 
wraddr = 7 
Next Prime from producer 1 is 2137
PutFifo:  2137 
wraddr = 8 
Next Prime from producer 1 is 2141
PutFifo:  2141 
wraddr = 9 
Next Prime from producer 1 is 2143
PutFifo:  2143 
wraddr = 0 
Next Prime from producer 1 is 2153
PutFifo:  2153 
wraddr = 1 
Performing thread-switch number 2. The system has been running for 101 ticks.
Switching from thread-ID 1 to thread-ID 2.

Next Prime from producer 2 is 5003
PutFifo:  5003 
wraddr = 2 
Next Prime from producer 2 is 5009
PutFifo:  5009 
wraddr = 3 
Next Prime from producer 2 is 5011
PutFifo:  5011 
wraddr = 4 
Next Prime from producer 2 is 5021
PutFifo:  5021 
wraddr = 5 
Next Prime from producer 2 is 5023
PutFifo:  5023 
wraddr = 6 
Next Prime from producer 2 is 5039
PutFifo:  5039 
wraddr = 7 
Next Prime from producer 2 is 5051
PutFifo:  5051 
wraddr = 8 
Next Prime from producer 2 is 5059
PutFifo:  5059 
wraddr = 9 
Next Prime from producer 2 is 5077
PutFifo:  5077 
wraddr = 0 
Next Prime from producer 2 is 5081
PutFifo:  5081 
wraddr = 1 
Performing thread-switch number 3. The system has been running for 201 ticks.
Switching from thread-ID 2 to thread-ID 3.

Next Prime from producer 3 is 8009
PutFifo:  8009 
wraddr = 2 
Next Prime from producer 3 is 8011
PutFifo:  8011 
wraddr = 3 
Next Prime from producer 3 is 8017
PutFifo:  8017 
wraddr = 4 
Next Prime from producer 3 is 8039
PutFifo:  8039 
wraddr = 5 
Next Prime from producer 3 is 8053
PutFifo:  8053 
wraddr = 6 
Next Prime from producer 3 is 8059
PutFifo:  8059 
wraddr = 7 
Performing thread-switch number 4. The system has been running for 301 ticks.
Switching from thread-ID 3 to thread-ID 4.

GetFifo:  5077 
rdaddr = 0 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 5077 
GetFifo:  5081 
rdaddr = 1 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 5081 
GetFifo:  8009 
rdaddr = 2 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 8009 
GetFifo:  8011 
rdaddr = 3 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 8011 
GetFifo:  8017 
rdaddr = 4 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 8017 
GetFifo:  8039 
rdaddr = 5 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 8039 
GetFifo:  8053 
rdaddr = 6 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 8053 
GetFifo:  8059 
rdaddr = 7 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 8059 
GetFifo:  5051 
rdaddr = 8 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 5051 
GetFifo:  5059 
rdaddr = 9 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 5059 
GetFifo:  5077 
rdaddr = 0 
Consumer 1 gets Prime 5077 
GetFifo:  5081
```

Could you please tell me why the first 30 primes get overwritten when all I do is just following the specification and just removing the comments from the code to activate what the instructor has prepared for us to study? I've been unable to complete this exercise for months since I'm not getting any good help. The first 30 primes are myseriously overwritten and the program should not be changed (it is homework). I asked the instructor and he didn't, said that I'm using newer versions of the software. I could try with older versions of the softare but that doesn't seem like a likely solution.

### Update

The strategy I can think of is start using the debugger and inspect the FIFO ADT during execution. I don't have much experience using gdb so please help me if you can.

Comment: You have wrap control so that when the writer reaches the end of the array, the next entry is placed at the start, but you do not have any over-filling control, so if the producers produce faster than the consumers consume, the producers overwrite unread data.  You need to ensure that the array `Fifo` is not over-filled.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You're right, increasing the FIFO size to 100 fixes the bug. Thank you, I accept your comment as an answer.

Comment: if jonathan is right, the easiest way is to use a "special value" that cannot be a valid produced value, and have the producer only put data into a slot that has that special value, if there aren't any, it would sleep.  The consumer will consume any value that isn't the special value and set that position to the special value.  If there is no data that isn't the special value, the consumer will sleep.

Comment: No, that doesn't fix the problem.  That's not the right thing to do.  If your timing changes, your code will exhibit the same behavior.

Comment: @xaxxon Then this is strange since the code was given to us by a course instructor and we shouldn't need to change it. The only reason I can think of this appearing is that computers were slower when this program first was written, but I do not understand how this can be used as education material if the code is not correct.

Comment: Vague title is not going to be helpful to future visitors to the site.

Comment: I was trying to say that increasing the size to 100 was not the answer.

Comment: raymond, suggest an edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code can't possibly be expected to work correctly if you don't uncomment the *Wait* and *Signal* calls inside the *PutFifo* and *GetFifo* functions. If it does appear to work under certain circumstances on a certain computer, that is pure luck.

First off, if one or more of the producer threads fill up the FIFO buffer before switching to one of the consumer threads, then some of that data is obviously going to be lost.

You can clearly see this in your example output. The producer threads have generated 38 values before the first consumer thread gets a chance to run. And because your buffer size is 10, the first value the consumer is going to read is actually the 31st value produced (i.e. the last value written to *wraddr* 0).

```
╔═══════╦════════╦═══════╗
║ count ║ wraddr ║ value ║
╠═══════╬════════╬═══════╣
║    .. ║     .. ║    .. ║
║    29 ║      8 ║  5051 ║
║    30 ║      9 ║  5059 ║
║    31 ║      0 ║  5077 ║ <- Consumer starts here
║    32 ║      1 ║  5081 ║
║    33 ║      2 ║  8009 ║
║    34 ║      3 ║  8011 ║
║    35 ║      4 ║  8017 ║
║    36 ║      5 ║  8039 ║
║    37 ║      6 ║  8053 ║
║    38 ║      7 ║  8059 ║
╚═══════╩════════╩═══════╝
```

Morever, if the consumer threads read more data than is available in the FIFO buffer before switching back to one of the producer threads, then they are going to end up reading the same values more than once. Again you can see this from your example output. The consumer thread reads items 31 to 38, then wraps around to items 29 and 30 (the last values at *wraddr* 8 and 9), before repeating item 31 again.

This isn't the worst thing that could happen though. In a true preemptive multithreading system, a producer thread could be preempted halfway through the *PutFifo* function. So imagine one of the producer threads is writing to the FIFO buffer when *wraddr* is 9. Let's say it executes these two lines.

```
Fifo[wraddr] = tal;       /* Write to FIFO array. */
wraddr = wraddr + 1;      /* Increase index into FIFO array,
```

At this point *wraddr* is 10, but before the function has a chance to check for the overflow (and wrap the index back to 0), the thread gets preempted by another one of the producer threads. And since *wraddr* is 10, this new producer is going to be writing past the end of the buffer, potentially causing the app to crash.

If it survives, *wraddr* will be incremented again (becoming 11), but it still won't wrap to zero, because the overflow check is expecting an exact match with the *FIFO_SIZE*. So even if it doesn't crash immediately, it's sure to crash at some point, because *wraddr* will just continue getting bigger and bigger, overwriting more and more memory.

The bottom line is if you want this code to work you are going to have to add the synchronisation calls.

Comment: I'm still studying this pattern for operating system assigments and I thank you for this information.

Answer (score 3):

#### Original notes 2013-05-05

In a comment, I noted:

> You have wrap control so that when the writer reaches the end of the array, the next entry is placed at the start, but you do not have any over-filling control, so if the producers produce faster than the consumers consume, the producers overwrite unread data. You need to ensure that the array `Fifo` is not over-filled.

[Nick Rosencrantz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/108207/nick-rosencrantz) observed:

> You're right, increasing the FIFO size to 100 fixes the bug.

Actually, increasing the FIFO size does *not* fix the bug; it simply avoids the bug for longer.  You need to keep track of whether the write pointer (index) is going to catch up with the read pointer, and either not add or delay adding a new number until one of the consumers has read the number at the read pointer so that there is space once more.

---

#### Actual testing of the code

The code in the question is the code from the exercise verbatim.  I'm not sure what the equipment described is, but the screen shots suggest Windows is involved.  I have a Mac.  Superficially, that makes testing the code hard — one of the files is assembler.  However, the code can easily be supplemented by Unix (POSIX pthread) implementations of the primitives.  Actually, the lab has been well designed; it was very easy to do the simulation.  However, you must take any results I report with an appropriate pinch of salt — a Mac is a very different machine.

1. I prefer functions declared before they're defined or used.

   ```
   #include <unistd.h>
   extern void fatal_error(char * msg);
   extern void Sleep (int n); 
   extern void Signal(int *sem);
   extern void Wait(int *sem);
   extern void PutFifo(int tal);
   extern int  GetFifo(void);
   extern void Producer(struct Prod * prodstruct);
   extern void Consumer(int * tal);
   ```
2. The `while (1);` loop in `fatal_error()` is a busy wait; I'd rather use [`pause()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pause.html).  However, it was never actually exercised, so maybe it doesn't matter.
3. The necessary `oslab_*()` primitives can be simulated with POSIX pthreads trivially:

   ```
   /* pthread implementation */
   #include <pthread.h>
   #include <time.h>

   static pthread_mutex_t mtx = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

   void oslab_begin_critical_region(void)
   {
       pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
   }
   void oslab_end_critical_region(void)
   {
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
   }
   int oslab_create_thread(int (*thread_function)(void *), void *data, unsigned int *stack)
   {
       typedef void *(*ThreadMain)(void *);
       static int threadnum = 0;
       pthread_t pth;
       pthread_attr_t pat;
       pthread_attr_init(&pat);
       pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&pat, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
       if (pthread_create(&pth, &pat, (ThreadMain)thread_function, data) != 0)
       {
           char buffer[128];
           sprintf(buffer, "Failed to create thread with stack %p\n", stack);
           fatal_error(buffer);
       }
       return ++threadnum;
   }
   void oslab_idle(void)
   {
       pause();
   }
   void oslab_yield(void)
   {
       struct timespec rqtp = { .tv_sec = 0, .tv_nsec = 1000000 };  // 1 millisecond
       if (nanosleep(&rqtp, 0) != 0)
           fatal_error("nanosleep failed\n");
   }
   /* end pthread implementation */
   ```
4. All the messages are in the irritating format `"\nMessage"`; that is a screwball format.  Rewrite them all so the newline is at the end, where the 'end of line' character always should be.
5. When the debug printing is enabled, the lines should be forced out.  I used `fflush(0)` (equivalent, in this context, to `fflush(stdout)`) after the debugging print statements.  An alternative (better) way to do that would be to call [`setvbuf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setvbuf.html) in `main()` to set line buffering.

   ```
   char buffer[BUFSIZ];
   setvbuf(stdout, buffer, _IOLBF, BUFSIZ);
   ```

#### Results

With these changes in place (leaving the synchronization primitives — calls to `Wait()`, `Signal()` and `oslab_yield()` — commented out), all hell breaks loose:

```
System starting...
Producer 1 is created with thread-ID 1
Producer 2 is created with thread-ID 2
Producer 3 is created with thread-ID 3
Consumer 1 is created with thread-ID 4
Consumer 2 is created with thread-ID 5
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0
Next Prime from producer 1 is 2003
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0
Next Prime from producer 2 is 5003
Next Prime from producer 3 is 8009
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0
Next Prime from producer 1 is 2011
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0
Next Prime from producer 2 is 5009
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0
Next Prime from producer 1 is 2017
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0
Next Prime from producer 3 is 8011
Next Prime from producer 2 is 5011
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0
Next Prime from producer 1 is 2027
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0
Consumer 1 gets Prime 0
Next Prime from producer 3 is 8017
Next Prime from producer 2 is 5021
Next Prime from producer 1 is 2029
Consumer 2 gets Prime 0
Consumer 1 gets Prime 2003
Consumer 2 gets Prime 2029
Next Prime from producer 1 is 2039
Next Prime from producer 3 is 8039
Next Prime from producer 2 is 5023
Consumer 1 gets Prime 8009
Consumer 2 gets Prime 2011
```

However, if you enable the synchronization primitives (but leave the debug code disabled), then you get sane behaviour: the consumer do not try to read the queue before there is data in the queue, and the writers do not try to write to the queue when there isn't space in the queue.

```
System starting...
Producer 1 is created with thread-ID 1
Producer 2 is created with thread-ID 2
Producer 3 is created with thread-ID 3
Consumer 1 is created with thread-ID 4
Consumer 2 is created with thread-ID 5
Next Prime from producer 1 is 2003
Next Prime from producer 2 is 5003
Next Prime from producer 3 is 8009
Consumer 1 gets Prime 2003
Consumer 2 gets Prime 5003
Next Prime from producer 1 is 2011
Next Prime from producer 3 is 8011
Next Prime from producer 2 is 5009
Next Prime from producer 2 is 5011
Consumer 1 gets Prime 8009
Consumer 2 gets Prime 2011
Next Prime from producer 1 is 2017
Next Prime from producer 3 is 8017
Consumer 1 gets Prime 8011
Consumer 2 gets Prime 5009
Next Prime from producer 2 is 5021
Next Prime from producer 1 is 2027
Next Prime from producer 3 is 8039
Next Prime from producer 2 is 5023
Consumer 1 gets Prime 5011
Consumer 2 gets Prime 2017
Next Prime from producer 3 is 8053
Next Prime from producer 1 is 2029
Next Prime from producer 2 is 5039
```

This is to be expected.  If you have true multi-core threading (Intel Core i7 does), then without the synchronization, you get all sorts of odd-ball behaviour.  With the synchronization, everything is calm.  I've let the code run free with the output going to file.  When the results are analyzed, you see one appearance of each of the primes 2003..4999, two appearances of each of the primes 5003..7993, and three appearances of each of the primes from 8009 upwards, which is what you'd expect.

If you enable the debugging code, you get to see more output:

```
System starting...
Producer 1 is created with thread-ID 1
Next Prime from producer 1 is 2003
Producer 2 is created with thread-ID 2
PutFifo:  2003
wraddr = 0
Producer 3 is created with thread-ID 3
Consumer 1 is created with thread-ID 4
GetFifo:  2003
rdaddr = 0
Consumer 2 is created with thread-ID 5
Next Prime from producer 2 is 5003
Next Prime from producer 3 is 8009
Consumer 1 gets Prime 2003
PutFifo:  5003
wraddr = 1
GetFifo:  5003
rdaddr = 1
Consumer 1 gets Prime 5003
Next Prime from producer 1 is 2011
PutFifo:  2011
wraddr = 2
GetFifo:  2011
rdaddr = 2
Consumer 2 gets Prime 2011
PutFifo:  8009
wraddr = 3
Next Prime from producer 2 is 5009
PutFifo:  5009
wraddr = 4
GetFifo:  8009
rdaddr = 3
Consumer 1 gets Prime 8009
Next Prime from producer 3 is 8011
GetFifo:  5009
PutFifo:  8011
rdaddr = 4
Next Prime from producer 1 is 2017
wraddr = 5
Consumer 2 gets Prime 5009
Next Prime from producer 2 is 5011
PutFifo:  5011
wraddr = 6
PutFifo:  2017
wraddr = 7
GetFifo:  8011
rdaddr = 5
Consumer 2 gets Prime 8011
GetFifo:  5011
rdaddr = 6
Next Prime from producer 3 is 8017
Consumer 1 gets Prime 5011
PutFifo:  8017
wraddr = 8
Next Prime from producer 2 is 5021
PutFifo:  5021
wraddr = 9
Next Prime from producer 1 is 2027
PutFifo:  2027
wraddr = 0
GetFifo:  2017
rdaddr = 7
Consumer 1 gets Prime 2017
```

This shows `wraddr` wrapping from 9 to 0.  It is otherwise verbose and unexciting.

#### Running GDB

It is not clear that you would be able to run GDB on the program in the original environment.  You're using home-brew threading (if you're using the original `oslab_lowlevel_c.c` and `oslab_lowlevel_asm.s` source), and GDB won't be aware of the multi-threading.

With the POSIX threading I've used, it would be possible to debug the code using GDB.

Comment: It is a very informative answer but I spoke with the instructor and we are not allowed to change the code. The exercise was to actually run the code in a simulator (that unfortunately is not available for Mac) or on the FPGA (which I've not yet managed to do) and get the correct results which seems undoable. I know I'm now screwing something up and I follow the instructions exactly and I still get the primes overwritten. I'd like to keep this exercise and build on it like I've previously been able to keep and build on exercises but this exercise seems faulty.

Comment: When you say 'not allowed to change the code', do you mean 'not allowed to remove the comments from before the synchronization operations' or something else?  Clearly, since most people on SO do not have access to the hardware/FGPA that's in your lab, we cannot replicate your exact scenario.  The changes I made were necessary to emulate your simulator (approximately the minimum necessary changes).  I really didn't change the operational code at all, apart from enabling the synchronization code. I fear no-one here on SO can help you much more for lack of the necessary equipment.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The instructor has instructed us to exctly follow the assignment and the asignment says in one excersise that we should remove the comments that will start more threads, Having done that and built it in the Nios 2 IDE, it is possible to run the project in a simulator without the actual hardware, the simulator is available from my university http://www.csc.kth.se/~emille/niisim/ I think this exercise might be wrong and not compatible with the latest version of the Quartus Nios 2 SDK. Then the run it, the ELF file can be loaded in the simulator.

Comment: Too much like hard work downloading, compiling and testing the simulator on an unsupported platform.

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way is to use a "special value" that cannot be a valid produced value, and have the producer only put data into a slot that has that special value, if there aren't any, it would sleep. The consumer will consume any value that isn't the special value and set that position to the special value. If there is no data that isn't the special value, the consumer will sleep.

Comment: Might the solution be even simpler, to call `oslab_yield();        /* Perhaps we should yield here? */` and let that code run but only for the `void Producer`? I'm trying that and then it seems to work and with FIFO 10 slots like it was meant to be, it was supposed to be there so that we should discover it from the hint in the code.

Comment: Yeah, I mean there's totally better ways than what I said.  I really hate "magic values" because you always end up setting them as an intentional real value even though you swore you never would.  That's why I put the "easiest way" part up there.. the code in the Wait function is fairly complex (relative to a magic value solution)